# How to list folder sizes with AWS CLI like du sh command or max depth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I can list out the buckets folders using:

`aws s3 ls s3://bucket/ --recursive  --human-readable --summarize`

But then I also get ALL the contents of the folders also. I just want a list like:

`/folder1 10GB`

`/folder2 6GB`

This way I know where to focus and dive deeper. Is this possible because I can't find it anywhere?

Comment: This is not a feature of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You will need to write your own script to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not available currently, though there is a feature request against the [aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) project under ["aws s3 ls" should have a summary-only option](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2250).

The comments also include some ideas for how you could use Bash scripting to produce what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: fixed it. And is much simpler now and should do exactly what you want.**

Trying to write a script to do this, but no promises on when or if it will ever do what you want. But you can check it here: https://github.com/thisaaronm/aws-s3-size (feel free to submit PRs too!)

Right now, it's not much any than just running the command you're running now, but I'm working through child directories in my dev branch.

And it's written pretty ugly right now.

Comment: Note: While testing this, I learned that there is a difference in how S3 creates the prefixes via the CLI vs the GUI. My script will (right now) only work on folders (prefixes) that have been created via the GUI. I'll try and figure out a way to address prefixes created via the CLI, but that'll be a little trickier.

Comment: @ thisAaronMdev Im still kinda new to all this and im having trouble. I use Wasabi which still uses s3 cli with just diff end point in profile. Ive tried to run your script on its own, using aws cli, and aws powershell adding it to my path. Not having any luck. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: @satori what type of error are you getting? Also, how were the original objects uploaded to S3 - GUI or CLI?

Comment: @ thisAaronMdev
Kind of a mixed bag...some via Arq GUI client for mac and the rest via WP site backup plugins. I get the same types of responses in both CLI and AWS Shell which lead me to believe its mostly noob syntax errors. See: [link](https://satori-design.d.pr/lOMHzI)

Comment: @ thisAaronMdev So I got it to run! The issue was I had to insert my Wasabi profile into the script, but that led to a different issue. After the first return of bucket size, it will then list the bucket again and then the first folder and stops. Each folder in the bucket is a sites backups, but I don't understand when they are in alpha order it only lists a folder halfway down named Hope. I was trying to see if I could sub some commands with s3cmd du, but so far no dice.

Comment: @satori sorry, was going to try to look into it today, but work got in the way. So, glad you got it to run. Is the issue now that not everything is appearing? If so, that's related to what I mentioned in my first comment about how S3 treats prefixes created via the GUI vs the CLI. In short, it APPEARS that only objects uploaded in the Web Console will appear via my script. Anything uploaded via the CLI or other plugin/API/etc, will not. I just tested this again - created a new bucket via CLI, then uploaded a folder with multiple files and directories - script only returns the bucket name.

Comment: @ thisAaronMdev Ahhh, ok. Thats weird! I didn't even know there was an identifier for that. I know its outside the scope of what I asked, but if you feel like dropping a lil knowledge how it knows its diff im curious:)

Comment: @satori I'm going to have to review my script. I threw it together pretty quickly, so I see things I could change. When I spoke with an AWS SA, he said: "S3 isn't a filesystem. 'prefixes' are just objects too and they might not exist in a bucket. I just created an object - s3://[bucket]/path/to/test/object.txt. All of the sub-prefix objects don't exist. aws s3 ls s3://[bucket]/ --recursive | grep '/$' yields nothing. Perhaps uploading through the console automatically creates those empty objects, but through the API does not. I think --recursive is showing actual objects"

Comment: @satori as to how it knows the difference? not sure. Maybe metadata we don't have access to or other AWS magic?

Answer (score 0):

A new solution in case you run across this like I did:

```
s3cmd ls "s3://<bucket>/<prefix>" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n 1 -P 20 -I{} s3cmd du -H {}
```